# Papers that debunk common myths in the history of mathematics

Tags: ho.history-overview, big-list

What are some good papers that debunk common myths in the history of mathematics?

To give you an idea of what I'm looking for, here are some examples.

Tony Rothman, ["Genius and biographers: The fictionalization of Evariste Galois,"](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/genius-and-biographers-the-fictionalization-of-evariste-galois) *Amer. Math. Monthly* 89 (1982), 84–106.  Debunks various myths about Galois, in particular the idea that he furiously wrote down all the details of Galois theory for the first time the night before he died.

Jeremy Gray, ["Did Poincaré say 'set theory is a disease'?"](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03024067), *Math. Intelligencer* 13 (1991), 19-22.  Debunks the myth that Poincaré said, "Later generations will regard *Mengenlehre* as a disease from which one has recovered."

Colin McLarty, [Theology and its discontents: The origin myth of modern mathematics](https://web.archive.org/web/20160720140113/https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michael.harris/theology.pdf). Debunks the myth that Gordan denounced Hilbert's proof of the basis theorem with the dismissive sentence, "This is not mathematics; this is theology!"

Some might say that my question belongs on the Historia Matematica mailing list; however, besides the fact that I don't subscribe to Historia Matematica, I think that the superior infrastructure of MathOverflow actually makes it a better home for the list I hope to create.  Still, maybe someone should let the Historia Matematica mailing list know that I'm asking the question here.

Comment: Let's hope John Stillwell checks in at some point on this question:He,of course,has a reputation as one of mathematics' most knowledgeable and prolific historical scholars.

Comment: Glad to oblige, Andrew.

Comment: Historia Matematica seems to be dead for quite a long time. (Otherwise: Please give a working link.) So: Why do you flog a dead horse?

Comment: I'm not sure that the Colin McLarty paper really 'debunks' the Gordan 'myth' so much as casts a different light on it...

Comment: @MariusKempe, indeed, McLarty shows that the quote is unreliably sourced and often misinterpreted, but he does not dispute Hilbert’s claim that: “P. Gordan had a certain unclear feeling of the transfinite methods in my first invariant proof [i.e. of the finiteness of complete systems] which he expressed by calling the proof ‘theological.’”

Answer (score 93):

For over a century, books published a picture of Legendre that was not in fact a picture of Legendre. There's an AMS notices [article](http://www.ams.org/notices/200911/rtx091101440p.pdf). Does a picture count as a myth?

Comment: That's very interesting, sigfpe. +1

Comment: I learnt it from the n-category cafe.

Comment: And there's a similar state of affairs about a picture of Bolyai, see [article in the *Notices*](http://www.ams.org/notices/201101/rtx110100041p.pdf).

Answer (score 42):

This entry is inspired by sigfpe's example of "picture as a myth".

There is an even more outrageous picture scam: for *centuries*, mathematics books featured [image]

this picture of [Euclid of Megara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_of_Megara), whereas the author of the Elements was [Euclid of Alexandria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid)!

**P.S.** I offered a prize to any student who can find a glaring error in our linear algebra text. No one succeeded, although in fairness to them, sleazy publisher cropped the picture.

Comment: To debunk: Behold!

Comment: It's difficult not to get confused here. Both Euclids look the same to me. Both of them have long beards, they both are holding a compass, etc. In the Legendre case the situation was easier: the fake Legendre had a wig whereas the real one did not.

Comment: It's easy: fake Euclid is wearing a bandana! Also, EVCLIDI MEGAREN should be a bit of a clue.

Comment: Great. Apparently medieval artists had a similar lack of clue about ancient Greece as the ones of today have about the Middle Ages. ;)

Comment: What was this linear algebra text that had *no* errors in the text?!

Answer (score 36):

There is a [nice article](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/gausss-day-of-reckoning) by Brian Hayes in the *American Scientist* (May-June 2006), "Gauss' Day of Reckoning," in which he looks at the history of the so-called "baby Gauss" story (that Gauss amazes his teacher by summing the first 100 positive integers).

There is a famous anecdote about Euler embarrassing Diderot in Catherine the Great's court. He claimed to have mathematical proof of the existence of God, when in fact he just stated mathematical nonsense (which Diderot did not understand): "*Monseur, $(a+b^n)/n=x$ donc Dieu existe; répondez!*" B. H. Brown tracked down the source of this myth in "The Euler-Diderot Anecdote" (*Amer. Math. Monthly*, Vol 49, 1942, reprinted in William Dunham's *The genius of Euler: reflections on his life and work* (2007))

Finally, there is a mathematical urban legend that I thought was surely was false, but is apparently true ([according to Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/college/homework/unsolvable.asp)). This is the story about the student who comes late to class and sees the homework written on the board. After a lot of effort he solves the problems. Only later did he discover that they were not homework, but open problems. It turns out that the student in the story was George Dantzig. Snopes cites a 1986 interview with Dantzig from the *College Mathematics Journal*.

Comment: Dantzig also recounts the story in his interview in More Mathematical People. He adds that Knuth had hailed him and said he (Dantzig) was now an influence on Christians in mid-west America; apparently the minister of the church (Norman Vincent Peale, perhaps?) was seated next to Dantzig on a plane and was explaining to him his views on positive thinking, and Dantzig had offered this story which the minister later used to illustrate his thesis in his sermon.

Answer (score 34):

Misconceptions about the Golden Ratio
George Markowsky
College Math Journal: Volume 23, Number 1, Pages: 2-19  1992

first paragraph...

The golden ratio, also called by different authors the golden section [Cox], golden number [Fi4], golden mean [Lin], divine proportion [Hun], and division in extreme and mean ratios [Smi], has captured the popular imagination and is discussed in many books and articles. Generally, its mathematical properties are correctly stated, but much of what is presented about it in art, architecture, literature, and esthetics is false or seriously misleading. Unfortunately, these statements about the golden ratio have achieved the status of common knowledge and are widely repeated. Even current high school geometry textbooks such as [Ser] make many incorrect statements about the golden ratio.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading a review of a more recent book that debunked many of the myths (e.g. by empirically measuring the most pleasing ratio of sides of rectangular objects).

Comment: You might be thinking of Mario Livio's book; there's a chapter where he does that.

Comment: @Victor: Maybe you were thinking of Mr. Markowsky's review of Mario Livio's book on $\phi$. It appeared several years ago in the Notices of the AMS and you can find it here: http://www.ams.org/notices/200503/rev-markowsky.pdf

Answer (score 29):

Historians like nothing better than to debunk other historians,
so there are plenty of papers shooting down one myth or another. 
I enjoy these papers as much as the next person, but sometimes the 
debunking becomes the new myth. So, if I may turn the question 
round a bit, here is a case where I think the original "myth" has 
merit, and I'm not convinced by the "debunking".

"Myth". The ancient Mesopotamians who compiled Plimpton 322 were
looking for Pythagorean triples and had a powerful method for
finding them. For example, they found the triple (13500,12709,18541).

"Debunking". By Eleanor Robson in Historia Mathematica 28 (2001) 167-206,
which may be viewed [here](http://www.hps.cam.ac.uk/people/robson/neither-sherlock.pdf).

Comment: I would like to know whether there are rejoinders to Rothman's article mentioned above. That Bell's Men of Mathematics is unreliable goes without saying. However, there are several things to object to in Rothman's article. It seems to have been written with an intense dislike for romantic sensibilities - or even republican sympathies - that passes itself off for a tone of objectivity. For Rothman, Galois's troubles - including being expelled for exposing the opportunism of his school's director - were "what might have been anticipated", and Galois's objections to this are "paranoia".

Comment: Not exactly a rejoinder to Rothman, but a nice attempt to tell the Galois story from a fresh point of view, is the novel *The French Mathematician* by Tom Petsinis (Walker & Company 1998).

Comment: @H A Helfgott: Such a rejoinder to Robson (not Rothman) was published by Britton, Proust, and Shnideer [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00407-011-0083-4).  See also [mathscinet review](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2838357).

Comment: @Mikhail Katz: Thanks. I found Robson's article to be written in an overly polemical fashion. Indeed, she acknowledges it is written polemically - the problem is that it gives the impression of debunking more than it does. It does do a good job of casting doubt (or even scorn) on speculation about applications - but it gives the impression of casting down on the non-myth above, while grudgingly acknowledging the grounds for it towards the end.

Comment: The link to the paper of Robson does not work.

Comment: A less technical version by Robson may be viewed at https://jmhammond.github.io/history/Robson2002.pdf

Answer (score 27):

One of the biggest myths in number theory is that work on Fermat's last theorem played a large role in the development of ideal theory and algebraic number theory. In fact it was much loftier goals such as the quest for higher reciprocity laws that were the true sources of inspiration. For references see e.g. Lemmermeyer's book "Reciprocity Laws" p. 15 (notes on Lagrange).

Speaking of FLT, recall the legend that Kummer submitted a false proof based on the erroneous assumption that cyclotomic number rings were UFDs. Edwards argued that this may be a myth and put forth an argument that, instead, Kummer's mistake was based on a simple error not related to any UFD assumption. However R. Bolling recently discovered new evidence that seems to lend strong support to the veracity to the claim that Kummer did in fact mistakenly assume facts equivalent to unique factorization in various rings of cylotomic integers in one of his early papers (which was not an attempted proof of FLT). So only part of this legend is actually true.

The above two paragraphs don't really do justice to the complex history. For a more faithful rendition I highly recommend that the interested reader also consult Franz Lemmermeyer's recent paper [1] which, imho, is one of the most interesting historical works on number theory in quite some time.

By the way, far less known than the constructivity of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes (cf. M. Hardy below) is the striking fact that Euclid's constructive proof generalizes quite widely - namely to any infinite ring having fewer units than elements.
For this little-known proof see my post here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1209616#p1209616 
http://google.com/groups?selm=y8zk5f3rn4e.fsf%40nestle.csail.mit.edu

[1] Franz Lemmermeyer.  Jacobi and Kummer's ideal numbers.
Abhandlungen aus dem Mathematischen Seminar der Universität Hamburg v. 79, 2, 2009, 165-187.
http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s12188-009-0020-5

Comment: As for the FLT legend, Boelling's work shows clearly that Kummer's erroneous manuscript had nothing to do with FLT. The topic of Kummer's research was the "splitting of primes" in cyclotomic rings, and his error is related with unique factorization. 

Comment: This is the first time I have ever heard a story in which Kummer made a mistake of assuming unique factorization.  In the story I have always heard, it was Lame who made this error, and Kummer who pointed it out.  See for example http://www.bookrags.com/research/fermats-last-theorem-wom/

Comment: Oops, too much cutiing and pasting in the middle of the night. Of course I didn't mean to say Kummer's false proof was on FLT (like Lame's). I corrected that. Thanks for the heads-up. 

Comment: Kummer did not assume unique factorization - he "proved" a theorem showing that the prime ideals above prime  p = 1 mod q are principal.
This implies, by what he would prove later (the class group is generated by ideals of degree 1) that the ring of integers in this
cyclotomic field has uique factorization. 

As for Lame's error: this was pointed out by Liouville - Kummer explicitly constructed a counterexample (23rd roots of unity) which (my guess) he learned from Jacobi. Jacobi probably didn't think for a second that this example might make history . . . 

Comment: Timothy, is it possible you never read Bell's Men Of Mathematics? Here's the Kummer story/legend/myth, from p.473: Kummer too had fallen afoul of the net which snared Cauchy, and for a time he believed that he had proved Fermat's "Last Theorem." Then Dirichlet, to whom the supposed proof was submitted for criticism, pointed out by means of an example that the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, contrary to Kummer's tacit assumption, does {\it not} hold in the field concerned. 

Comment: Dear @BillDubuque, the link to your post is broken. Is there another source?

Comment: @Arrow Yes, there is a copy [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2653/242) on Math.SE.

Answer (score 18):

I like this question very much - many popular history of mathematics books seem filled with legends more than history.

I would expand the question "What are some good papers that debunk common myths...?" to include books as well as papers.  Maybe the best books to debunk myths are books that directly discuss and include the primary source material (in translation, perhaps).  A fantastic recent book in this spirit is "The Mathematics of Egypt, China, India, and Islam:  A Sourcebook," edited by Victor J. Katz.  This is a great value as well!  For example, an scholarly translation of the Chinese "Nine Chapters on the Mathematical Art" costs around 350 dollars on Amazon -- but one can instead find it in this sourcebook, together with a multitude of other translated texts, for around 50 or 60 dollars.

To demonstrate that this book addresses your specific question, on pages 467-477 you can find a translation of the Bijaganita of Bhaskara II.  At the end is Verse 129, the end of which is translated, "Hence, for the sake of brevity, the square-root of the sum of the squares of the arm and upright is the hypotenuse:  thus it is demonstrated.  And otherwise, when one has set down those parts of the figure there, [merely] seeing [it is sufficient].

The author of this section then mentions "These verses are presumably the ultimate source of the widespread legend that Bhaskara gave a proof of the Pythagorean theorem containing only the square figure shown in figure 4.19 and the word 'Behold!' "

The figure (4.19 in the book) is not among the verses in an old text, as far as I know.  I think that Indian texts of the period were traditionally written on palm leaves (which degrade somewhat quickly), and copied every generation or two, so we don't have very old texts.  In any case, the "Behold!" legend for the Pythagorean theorem seems to be a myth or at least a vigorous embellishment of history.

Answer (score 15):

"[Prime Simplicity](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00283-009-9064-8)", *Mathematical Intelligencer*, volume 31, number 4, pages 44‒52, by me and Catherine Woodgold, debunks the widespread belief that Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes is a proof by contradiction.  The proof that Euclid actually wrote is simpler and better than the proof by contradiction often attributed to him.

Comment: A similar mistaken belief is that Cantor's diagonal argument is a 
proof by contradiction.

Comment: I can't access Michael's article, but I am intrigued: aren't proofs of non-existence categorized as "proofs by contradiction"? How does Cantor's diagonal argument not qualify?

Comment: Just as Euclid proves "given finitely many primes, you can
find another one," Cantor proves "given countably many real numbers,
you can find another one." Also, just as Euclid's new prime can be
constructed from the given primes, Cantor's new real can be constructed from the given reals.

Comment: I agree that there are constructive aspects in both arguments. But the key point is what are "given" reals. Cantor's proof starts with $\textit{assuming}$ that a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ exists and specifying or fixing it. The conclusion is that there is a number not in the image of $f$, which is a contradiction. (This is quantified over all putative bijections.) This seems a quintessential proof by contradiction to me. What do you make of Liouville's proof that transcendent numbers exist? 

Comment: Victor, Cantor's proof may be phrased as by contradiction, but that is not the most elegant nor even the most natural way. You can present it as follows. Given any *function* f:N-->R, the well-known diagonal procedure produces a real number not in the range. Therefore no function from N to R is surjective. This is not a proof by contradiction, any more than the proof that there is no largest natural number: given any n, n+1 is larger. You do not need to "assume n is the largest".

Comment: Also, it is important to distinguish between considerations of "logical directness" if you will, i.e. whether a proof proceeds by constradiction, and considerations of constructiveness. They are related but separate; it is possible for a proof to fall in each of the 2 x 2 categories of this classification.

Comment: I don't know whether Cantor's original proof begins by assuming such a bijection exists, but I'd be a bit surprised if it did.  I think the more natural way is by showing that for any injection there are reals not in its image.

Comment: I've seen it claimed that although proofs of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ are by contradiction, they are not indirect proofs, since the nature of the statement being proved is negative (it asserts non-existence of something).

Comment: Thanks to John, Pietro and Michael for clarifications! It was facile to interpret John's invokation of Cantor's $\textit{diagonal argument}$ as a reference to the proof that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ aren't equipotent. Michael's last point is what I meant: some statements are negative by nature, so it seems technically impossible to prove them "directly". 

Comment: By the way, Michael: Cantor's diagonal argument, while elegant and best known, is not his original proof. It was found many years later.

Comment: This distaste for proofs by contradiction really belongs in the sci.math newsgroup. What on earth is wrong with a proof by contradiction? It's not at all the same thing as a non-constructive proof! It seems to me that both Euclid's and Cantor's proofs flow most naturally when cast as proof by contradiction. So what's the problem? Why is proof by contradiction seen as something to be avoided?

Comment: TonyK, you're very much mistaken to think that Euclid's proof flows best as a proof by contradiction.  It's simpler when done the way Euclid did it originally.  It's also misleading, as seen by what G. H. Hardy did with it.  He said if you multiply all the (assumed finitely many) primes and add 1, the number you get is not divisible by any prime and is therefore itself prime, thereby contradicting the initial assumption.  The conclusion that multiplying the first $n$ primes and adding 1 always yields a prime then becomes tempting.  But it is false.

Comment: Victor, you are quite right.  Several years ago (in 2003, I think?) I created a Wikipedia article on Cantor's first uncountability proof, in which I stated that contrary to what most mathematicians believe, it was not his diagonal argument, which came later.  The article has since benefited from the contributions of others, especially Robert Gray.

Comment: It occurs to me now that I do remember some details of Cantor's original proof of uncountability of the reals, and it focused on real algebraic numbers: it showed that the set of real algebraic numbers is countable; then it showed that that's enough to prove some reals are not algebraic.  Cantor constructed a real not in the sequence he started with, by a method that will work for any sequence.  So he did not start with an assumption that some sequence contains all reals.  Thus it was not a proof by contradiction.

Comment: http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/

Comment: In fact diagonalization was actually discovered first by du Bois-Reymond in his pioneering work on "orders of infinity" where he diagonalized on growth rates of functions. So its attribution to Cantor is another legend.


Comment: But was Cantor influenced by du Bois-Reymond or did he do it independently?

Comment: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/the-no-self-defeating-object-argument-revisited/

Comment: Maybe I should look at Terrence Tao's blog more often.

He says "it was pointed out" to him that Euclid's theorem can be proved in such a way that the argument by contradiction makes up only a small portion of the whole argument.  In fact, last year I pointed this out to him when he visited Minneapolis.  (But maybe I'm not the only one?)

Is he the only Fields Medalist who's polymathic enough to write a blog on such a diverse array of topics?  Or did I miss all the others?

Comment: @TonyK : I think my previous comment addressed to you did not rely on stackexchange's notification system, so herewith this notice.  You're quite mistaken to think that a "distaste for proofs by contradiction" is at work here, and you go deeply into error about the form of Euclid's argument that flows best, and you are breathtakingly unaware of the bad consequences that follow from thinking it's a proof by contradiction.  I was unaware when our paper on this was published, of one of the most spectacular examples, but this is a true story: A student, under the$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$mistaken impression that Euclid had claimed that if $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are the first $n$ primes, then $1+p_1\cdots p_n$ is prime, found numerous counterexamples and concluded that Euclid's proof is erroneous. Our paper explains why that error does not arise when Euclid's proof is presented, but does arise when its transformation into a proof by contradiction is presented. $\qquad$

Answer (score 14):

There is a rumor (a myth?) in holomorphic dynamics about a rivalry between Fatou and Julia competing for the 1918 Grand Prize of the french science academy. In fact Fatou never submitted a memoir for the Prize.

What we now call the Julia set was first defined in a note in *Comptes Rendus* by Montel, and is the starting point for the work of Fatou and Julia. Fatou published a few notes on the subject in the *Comptes Rendus* before Julia, who started a quarrel, claiming priority for the results. Fatou didn't try to fight back, apparently because he didn't bother, and the Academia fullfilled the wish of Julia. This may be the source of the rumor.

You may also know the Parseval formula about the relationship between the square of the L2 norm of a function and its Fourier coefficients. This formula is due to Fatou. H. Lebesgue did the case of a bounded function, and Fatou extended it to any square integrable functions. This made a big impression on Lebesgue.

This is exposed in a recent book by Michele Audin entitled "Fatou, Julia, Montel (...)"

Comment: What's the exact reference for Montel's paper where he introduced the Julia set ?

Comment: @Eremenko Points in the Julia set are called irregular points by Montel. From Audin's book (VI.3), they appear in the 1903 and 1904 CRAS Montel's notes and in its thesis. They also appear in a 1906 CRAS note of Fatou.

Comment: Montel calls irregular the points where SOME family of functions is not normal. He did not consider families of iterates before Fatou.

Comment: I cannot resist quoting the late Adrien Douady about this terminology: "Fatou has done many things, so "Fatou set" would be ambiguous, while Julia...".

Comment: @coudy: The claim you attribute to Michele Audin is simply not true. What is called nowadays Julia set was introduced for the first time by Fatou. And the more general notion  that Montel introduced is called "the set of irregular points", as Montel himself called it.

Answer (score 13):

Check out "Life on the Mathematical Frontier: Legendary Figures and Their Adventures" by
Roger Cooke in the April 2010 issue of the Notices (Volume 57, Number 4, pages 464–475), available online at http://www.ams.org/notices/201004/rtx100400464p.pdf .

I hope someone will follow up on Cooke's "Modest Proposal" (see page 473): "I would like to invite some ambitious mathematician with time on his/her hands to write a monograph on the role played by legends in the mathematical community. Or perhaps someone would be willing to set up the mathematical equivalent of the snopes.com website, where mathematical “urban legends” can be checked out."

Comment: A perfect example of what I'm looking for!  It's embarrassing how far behind I've gotten on reading the Notices...

Comment: Cooke's paper mentions several other papers of the type I'm interested in.  I'll mention just one: "The So-Called Euler-Diderot Incident" by R. J. Gillings, Amer. Math. Monthly 61 (1954), 77-80.  Gillings traces the legend that Euler confounded Diderot with a nonsensical mathematical proof of the existence of God to the memoirs of Dieudonne Thiebault.  Thiebault does tell the story, but in his account it's a Russian philosopher (not Euler), and Diderot knew it was nonsense but kept quiet because he sensed they were having him on.  Thiebault also says he's not sure the story was true. 

Answer (score 10):

Here is an paper on this subject:
Mathematical Myths
G. A. Miller
National Mathematics Magazine, Vol. 12, No. 8 (May, 1938), pp. 388-392

This is available on [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3028621)

Answer (score 9):

[Was Cantor Surprised?](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/AMM-March11_Cantor.pdf) published in Monthly is debunking (or trying to do so) that Cantor was so surprised when he discovered $I=[0,1]$ and $I^2$ have the same cardinality 
that he said “I see it, but I don’t believe it!”. The abstract of the paper reads as follows:

> **Abstract**. We look at the circumstances and context of Cantor’s famous remark, “I see it, but I don’t believe it.” We argue that,
>   rather than denoting astonishment at his result, the remark pointed to
>   Cantor’s worry about the correctness of his proof.

Answer (score 8):

There have been recent articles in *The Mathematical Intelligencer* about the well-known rivalry/animosity between Erdős and Selberg. Didier [adds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26613/papers-that-debunk-common-myths-in-the-history-of-mathematics#comment56771_26646) [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20110605193910/https://cs.nyu.edu/spencer/erdosselberg.pdf), pointing to an article of Graham and Spencer that appeared in *The Mathematical Intelligencer*. Emerton [adds](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26613/papers-that-debunk-common-myths-in-the-history-of-mathematics#comment56924_26646) [this link](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Egoldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf), pointing to an article by Goldfeld on the controversy.

Comment: What is the myth here?

Comment: Legend has it that the two were planning a joint publication when Selberg overheard someone say something like, "Hey, have you heard that Erdos and somebody-or-other have an elementary proof of the Prime Number Theorem?" The legend continues, that Selberg, not wishing to go down in history as "somebody-or-other," rushed the proof into print without waiting for Erdos, got all the credit, the Fields medal, etc. 

I haven't seen the Intelligencer and don't know what, if anything, it has to say about the legend. 

Comment: Kevin, could you please provide more specific references?

Comment: http://cs.nyu.edu/spencer/erdosselberg.pdf

Comment: One should also consider the reference http://math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf, written by D. Goldfeld, which contains quotes from Selberg disputing the account of Straus that is given in the reference mentioned by Didier Piau.

Comment: I had not heard of the legend mentioned by Gerry, but it seems incredibly biased. 

Comment: @Did The link is down.

Comment: @Todd, the Spencer & Graham paper is currently available at http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/manuscripts/erdosselberg.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks very much!

Comment: While this question is on the front page, I Wayback'd @Did's link.

Answer (score 8):

David Fowler's book "The Mathematics Of Plato's Academy: A New Reconstruction" sets out to deconstruct the myth that "the early Pythagoreans based their mathematics on commensurable magnitudes, but their discovery of the phenomenon of incommensurability (the irrationality of the square root of 2) showed that this was inadequate; this provoked problems in the foundation of mathematics that were not resolved before the discovery of the proportion theory that we find in Book V of Euclid's Elements". The arguments and conclusions are complex and interesting; here is a review with some of the main points: http://www.maa.org/publications/maa-reviews/the-mathematics-of-platos-academy-a-new-reconstruction.

Comment: The link in this answer appears to be dead.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: I repaired the link.

Answer (score 7):

I would expand the question "What are some good papers that debunk common myths...?" to include web pages as well as papers. Naturally, there is a couple of candidate web pages in the reference section of the note mentioned by **sigfpe**. Another candidate might be http://www.snopes.com/science/nobel.asp where the myth of the rivalry between A. Nobel and Mittag-Leffler is debunked (to some extent).

Comment: Snopes.com is a great website and I thought carefully about whether to phrase my question to include it or not.  I decided to focus on papers because on average, people take more care with their research when publishing a paper than when posting something on a website.  Snopes.com may be an exception because they take great pains to be accurate.  However, often when I see a website that purports to debunk a myth, I'm not sure whether to believe it.  If there are exceptionally good websites then people should mention them, but be aware that I put a very high premium on reliability.

Comment: If we're happier with a paper than a website for the matter of Nobel and Mittag-Leffler, there is John E. Morrill, A Nobel Prize in Mathematics, American Math Monthly, December 1995, 888-891, and the works that Morrill cites.

Answer (score 7):

I think the myth that Kolmogorov was the first to come up with the idea of basing probability theory on measure theory is very common. This myth is debunked in

The Sources of Kolmogorov’s Grundbegriffe

G.Shafer and V.Vovk, The Sources of Kolmogorov’s Grundbegriffe, Statist. Sci. Volume 21, Number 1 (2006), 70-98. [Online (free)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-21/issue-1/The-Sources-of-Kolmogorovs-Grundbegriffe/10.1214/088342305000000467.full).

Comment: Interesting paper...thanks!  But does it really say what you claim it says?  I quote: "Frechet thought of probability as an application of mathematics, not as a branch of pure mathematics itself, so he did not think he was axiomatizing probability theory.  It was Kolmogorov who first called Frechet’s theory a foundation for probability
theory."  Looks pretty close to crediting Kolmogorov with the idea of using measure theory as a foundation for probability theory.

Comment: I think a common view was that Kolmogorov provided an incomplete framework for probability. Frequentists, Subjectivists etc. would provide different axiomatizations giving rise to probabilities, based on something more empirical.  

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: oh no, have *you* just critisized Kolmogorov?

Comment: @Ilya Am I criticising you if I say that *you* did not invent the calculus?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: certainly depends on the tone. you should have taken my original comment with a grain of salty joke :) I'm going to ask a question regarding the history of probability and measure theory on MSE in 5 minutes, may be of your interest.

Answer (score 7):

Blaszczyk, Katz, and Sherry, "Ten Misconceptions from the History of Analysis and Their Debunking," http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.4153

The questions they address are:

1. Were the founders of calculus working in a numerical vacuum?
2. Was Berkeley’s criticism coherent?
3. Were d'Alembert’s anticipations ahead of his time?
4. Did Cauchy replace infinitesimals by rigor?
5. Was Cauchy’s 1821 "sum theorem" false?
6. Did Weierstrass succeed in eliminating infinitesimals?
7. Did Dedekind discover the essence of continuity?
8. Who invented Dirac’s delta function?
9. Is there continuity between Leibniz and Robinson?
10. Is Lakatos’ take on Cauchy tainted by Kuhnian relativism?

The main thread of their revisionist picture is that 17th- and 18th-century analysis had foundations that were far more rigorous and well-defined than most modern mathematicians have been led to believe.

Comment: I think these arguments actually show a weaker claim: “17th- and 18th-century analysis *could have* had foundations that were far more rigorous and well-defined”.

Comment: 10 doesn't seem a question about the history of mathematics, but the history of the philosophy of mathematics.

Answer (score 7):

There is the widespread myth that Cauchy gave an epsilon-delta definition of continuity. For Cauchy's definition, see http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/bradleypage26.pdf

To respond to Timothy Chow's comment, there is a famous essay by historian Judith Grabiner entitled "who gave you the epsilon?" with the implied answer being "Cauchy". This can be viewed at http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=691368

It should be noted that not all historians agree with Grabiner. Thus, Schubring in a recent text comments: "I am criticizing historiographical approaches like that of Judith Grabiner where one sees epsilon-delta already realized in Cauchy".  This can be viewed at http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10699-015-9424-0

Comment: Interesting.  I have never heard this myth before.  I have always heard epsilons and deltas attributed to Weierstrass.

Comment: @TimothyChow, I added some sources to my *answer* to respond to your query. Let me know if you would like additional details.

Comment: About Cantor's surprise, I read once he did write in French to Dedekind "je le vois, mais je ne le crois  pas...". I don't know whether this is a myth or not.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, I am not sure why you left this *comment* here. I don't seem to have written anything about Cantor in my *answer* here, though I did in other *answers*.  At any rate, a comment of this sort by Cantor seems to be on record.  The only question is, how does one interpret it.  There have been dramatically different interpretations. Why are you interested in this?

Comment: I got mistaken, I commented above the answer about Cantor's surprise instead of below. I'm interested in this, because I'd like to know why Cantor wrote in French. How was French considered in Germany at that time ?

Answer (score 7):

Gauss made a famous statement:

> I protest first of all against the use of an infinite quantity as a completed one, which is never permissible in mathematics. The infinite is only a *façon de parler*, where one is really speaking of limits to which certain ratios come as close as one likes while others are allowed to grow without restriction.

This statement is often used to claim that Gauss was opposed to the use of infinite sets. In the paper ["Gauss on Infinity"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086079900296), (*Historia Mathematica* 6 (1979), 430-436), W. C. Waterhouse shows that Gauss was actually talking about the sloppy use of "circles of infinite radius" in a fallacious geometric proof by H. Schumacher of the parallel postulate. **Infinite sets do not even come up**, but rather it is the imprecise use of what we would now formalize as "unlimited non-standard real numbers" that Gauss is objecting to.

The article goes on to show that, curiously, it seems that it was Lipschitz, when writing to Cantor, who first interpreted the above statement by Gauss as criticizing the use of infinite sets.

I will now add my own statement going beyond Waterhouse's paper. It seems that Gauss's full criticism of Schumacher's proof, not just the excerpt commonly used, is saying that non-Euclidean planes have non-zero curvature, and it seems likely to me that if done with non-standard analysis, that is what Schumacher's proof would show, once the fallacious step was removed.

Answer (score 7):

Frank Nelson Cole's own 1903 paper: [On The Factoring of Large Numbers](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183417760), discussed in another [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207321/how-did-cole-factor-267-1-in-1903), debunks the myth that he factored $M_{67}$ with "3 years of Sundays" using only trivial trial division.

What is yet to be debunked, but many have found suspicious, is whether he presented his results to the AMS by "silently multiplying the factors together."

**Added Later**

Isaac Grosof, in what appears to be the good-natured SIGBOVIK proceedings of April 1, 2019 ([link](http://sigbovik.org/2019/proceedings.pdf) to PDF), estimates the time complexity of various methods of multiplication - he performs the multiplication of the factors of $M_{67}$ himself on pencil-and-paper.  Grosof concludes that if Cole did multiply at the chalkboard, he might have used lattice multiplication, which Grosof was able to do error-free in about 10 minutes.

(H/T to @Arcorann for [pointing this out](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/11835) on hsm.stackexchange.)

Comment: Gridgeman's account in "The search for perfect numbers" (*New Scientist* 334 (1963), 86-88) reads, "F. N. Cole walked on to the platform and, without saying a single word, wrote two large numbers on the blackboard. He multiplied them out in longhand, and equated the result to $2^{67}-1$. (Subsequently, in private, Cole said that those few minutes at the blackboard had cost him three years of Sundays.)" Cole's paper makes it clear that he did not just use trial division, but Gridgeman doesn't claim that, and it's still possible that Cole spent 3 years of Sundays on this problem.

Comment: Is there another published version of this story that claims that Cole used trial division? I've seen it claimed that E.T. Bell perpetuated the story, but it doesn't seem to be in *Men of Mathematics*. Did Bell record the story somewhere else?

Comment: @TimothyChow I think I heard this story maybe from James Roy Newman's edited "The World of Mathematics, Vol. 1" chapter "The Queen of Mathematics" by Bell - https://archive.org/details/TheWorldOfMathematicsVolume1/page/n521 As for whether it was meant to be "three years of **trial division**" - that was the impression I got reading this story, and also listening to the "This American Life" podcast referenced in the linked question.  Paul Hoffman (the storyteller in TAL) wrote a nice biography of Erdos, maybe in TAL case he left his listeners with too much to fill in?

Comment: Thanks! Bell wrote: Cole−who was always a man of very few words−walked to the board and, saying nothing, proceeded to chalk up the arithmetic for raising 2 to the sixty-seventh power. Then he carefully subtracted 1. Without a word he moved over to a clear space on the board and multiplied out, by longhand, 193,707,721 x 761,838,257,287. The two calculations agreed...For the first and only time on record, an audience of the American Mathematical Society vigorously applauded the author of a paper delivered before it. Cole took his seat without having uttered a word. Nobody asked him a question.

Answer (score 6):

Historians of mathematics get very cross if you dare to say "Pythagoras's theorem." You have to say, "The Pythagorean theorem," to emphasize that it wasn't the brainwave of a man called Pythagoras. Indeed, that fact, as well as the irrationality of the square root of 2, were (I read) probably known long before Pythagoras, and the only Greek proofs we know of came much later. As for the story that the penalty for revealing the irrationality of the square root of 2 to outsiders was death ...

Comment: How can you know the irrationality of the square root of 2 without having a proof? Most sources I know place the first proofs after 450 BC, long after Pythagoras had died.

Comment: As I sang at the Joint Math Meetings a few years ago, to the tune of Bay Mir Bistu Sheyn, The square root of two/Give credit where it's due/Pythagoras' crew/Proved it's irrational.

Answer (score 6):

Donald E. Knuth's ["Johann Faulhaber and sums of powers"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CA/9207222) debunks common belief (mentioned at [at Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaulhabersFormula.html), for example) that Faulhaber was first to discover Bernoulli formula and even (to some extent) Bernoulli numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Myths can be [such nice inventions](http://www.raygirvan.co.uk/apoth/udo.htm), one should invent more of them!

Comment: Cute, even if 61 days late.

Comment: The link in this answer appears to be dead.

Comment: It is now here: http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/mandelset/mandelmonk/mandelmonk.html

Comment: @ThomasRiepe: is that link dead too?

Comment: http://users.math.yale.edu/public_html/People/frame/Fractals/MandelSet/MandelMonk/MandelMonk.html (While the article is quite entertaining, please be sure to note the date that it was written, as shown at the end of the article.)

Answer (score 5):

B. H. Brown debunks in [**1**] the myth that "Algebra was Hebrew to Diderot" (cf. E. T. Bell, *Men of Mathematics*, NY, 1937, pp. 146-147).

Gillings mentions in his note that it is D. Thiébault's account the only authority in the Euler-Diderot anecdote (even though "Thiébault himself was not convinced of the truth of it...").

It is important to add that in Thiébault's version of the story there is no explicit reference to the name of L. Euler.

**References**

[**1**] B. H. Brown. *The Euler-Diderot Anecdote*. Amer. Math. Monthly. Vol. **49**, Issue 5, 1942, pp. 302-303.

[**2**] R. J. Gillings. *The So-called Euler-Diderot Incident.* Amer. Math. Monthly. Vol. **61**, Issue 2, 1954, pp. 77-80.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question, but a favourite paper of mine along the debunking lines is Peter Neumann’s “A lemma that is not Burnside’s”.

http://www.appliedprobability.org/data/files/TMS%20articles/4_2_11.pdf

In which he observes that the orbit counting lemma (the number of orbits of a permutation group is equal to the average number of fixed points of its elements), which was frequently referred to as “Burnside’s Lemma”, is not actually due to Burnside.

His goal - to correct the misattribution before it was too late - seems to have been realised, because nowadays it is normally called the Cauchy-Frobenius Lemma or just the “orbit counting theorem”.

Comment: This reminds me of a so-called "Arnold's principle": Results are never named after their  inventors. "Arnold's principle" is of course recursiv and can be applied to itself.

Answer (score 3):

There are stories about work of Banach being written up by people other than Banach. Details and debunking links available on another MO thread, [Who wrote up Banach's Thesis?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111724/who-wrote-up-banachs-thesis)

Comment: Good one. Note especially the [recent answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/407911) that has not yet been highly upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

A recent one could be Peter Milne's "On Gödel Sentences and What They Say" Philosophia Mathematica (III) 15 (2007), 193–226. doi:10.1093/philmat/nkm015 debunking the myth that Gödel sentences are true because they say of themselves that they are unprovable.

Sorry, I realize this is not exactly what was being asked. However, there is still some analogy with the pattern "someone was believed to do or say something while in fact he/she didn't".

Comment: You're right; this is not quite what I asked for.  Misconceptions about the content of mathematical theorems are not the same as myths in the history of mathematics.  As far as Goedel is concerned, my favorite expose of nonsensical interpretations of Goedel's theorem is Torkel Franzen's book "Goedel's Theorem: An Incomplete Guide to Its Use and Abuse."

By the way, if you read Milne's paper carefully, you'll see that your description of its contents is not quite accurate.

Comment: Cf. this answer on Math.StackExchange.com: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/845583

Answer (score -4):

Anellis, I.H. (1995), “Peirce Rustled, Russell Pierced : How Charles Peirce and Bertrand Russell Viewed Each Other's Work in Logic, and an Assessment of Russell's Accuracy and Role in the Historiography of Logic”, *Modern Logic* 5, 270–328.  [Online](http://www.cspeirce.com/menu/library/aboutcsp/anellis/csp&br.htm).

Answer (score -4):

This myth is in living memory and I have not seen it debunked in print. The myth is that the Appel-Haken proof of the four colour theorem was controversial when it was published because it was a computer proof. This makes a good story but is it true?

Comment: FWIW, R.Diestel writes in Graph Theory that the original approach of Appel-Haken "has not been immune to criticism, *not* only because of their use of a computer".

Comment: This is certainly true.  Nobody needs to write an article "debunking" this one because philosophers have written entire journal articles questioning the status of the theorem.  See for example Thomas Tymoczko, "The four-color problem and its philosophical significance," J. Phil. 76 (1979), 57-83.

Comment: This article says in the opening paragraphs that mathematicians accept that this is a proof of the four colour theorem. The myth is that mathematicians did not accept this proof because it was a computer proof (not for reasons that Olivier refers to). 

Comment: Well, you didn't say "mathematicians" in your original statement, and you only said "controversial," not "did not accept."  But certainly, over the years, I have personally encountered several mathematicians who have expressed dissatisfaction with Appel, Haken, and Koch's use of a computer in the proof.  They wanted a humanly-comprehensible, elegant proof.  Now, to say that the mathematical community as a whole rejected the proof is certainly false, but I don't recall anyone ever claiming this.  Maybe it's a myth that there ever was such a myth?

Comment: I certainly didn't accept the Appel-Haken proof (until Gonthier did a fully verified machine-checked version), for the same reasons I don't (yet) accept the Hales's proof of the Kepler conjecture. If you run a computer program as part of the proof, then you also have to supply a correctness proof of the actual computer program you used, before you really have a full proof. (And indeed, Hales and his collaborators are currently developing a fully machine-checked version.) 

Comment: In other words you want computer proofs to be peer reviewed.:)